# How to prevent outer scrollviewer from overriding inner scrollviewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollbar

I have the following section within my Grid:

```
<ScrollViewer   Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" CanContentScroll="True"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

        <!-- other controls such as sliders, Textboxes and so on -->

        <Border Height="200" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="auto" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LogOutput}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

If I add a very long text into the `LogOuput` (tested with "Ipsum Lorem"), for some reason the width of my border increases and the outer `ScrollViewer` is showing a horizontal scrollbar.

What I would like to have, is that the width of the border doesn't change (always stretching to the available space of this grid column) and the inner `ScrollViewer` should show the horizontal scrollbar.
I know I could achieve this, by setting a fixed width to the border, however - as mentioned - I want the border to stretch to the available space.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you need `HorizontalScrollBar` by the outer `ScrollViewer`?

Comment: @Rekshino unfortunately yes. This should be shown for example, if the user resizes the window and the grid column gets too small for the other controls in this column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the `Width` of inner `ScrallViewer` to the width of column:

```
<Border Height="200" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Width="{Binding Path=ColumnDefinitions[putColIndexHere], Converter={StaticResource ColDefinitionToWidthConverter}, ConverterParameter=30, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="auto" Background="Cyan"
                    >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StrTest}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

and `Convert` method can looks like:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{   
    if(value is System.Windows.Controls.ColumnDefinition colDef)
    {
        return colDef.ActualWidth + colDef.Offset - int.Parse(parameter as string) ;
    }
    return value;
}
```